# Mouse cursor Lag in Unity Editor user interface

Tags: unity-game-engine, lag

I have 144 Hz monitor, when I move mouse around Unity Editor interface the it feels like the Unity drops refresh rate to 30 Hz (The mouse movment is very laggy, compared to other software's interfaces). Any suggestions how to solve it? THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after digging around I found that GSYNC was the issue. After switching to ONLY FULL SCREEN mode it worked!

Comment: This made a huge difference! Don't forget to set your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 5):

While the accepted answer certainly does work, if you rather use a targeted approach you can also change the monitor refresh technology for Unity.exe to fixed in the control panel. This will address it for Unity and not force GSYNC in full screen only for other apps. You have to restart Unity for it to take affect.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXbRC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some editor processes running in the background? Perhaps from a 3rd party tool? Sounds like it is checking for something expensive.

Go to Window/Analysis/Editor Iteration Profiler to test what could be slowing down the editor.

Another thing that comes to mind, are you using a laptop with a discrete GPU? You could have a power saving feature enabled to run graphically intensive applications (such as the Unity Editor) at a lower frame rate.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help :( But thank you for the suggestion.